# Storing/Retrieving a java collection in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We are trying to access a java arraylist and retrieve value from it per message on a proxy service.Can this arraylist be loaded into wso2 registry and retrieved(also add values into the arraylist as required) from the proxy service.If so,please guide as i am completely new to wso2 esb.I am particularly looking for solutions in wso2 esb.
TO make things more clear

well, we havent done anything concrete, we are trying to find different approaches to the requirement.There is a set of values in a arraylist and we need to store and access it from wso2 esb(preferable registry). For each message coming in via the JMS proxy we need to retreive and remove the field from the arraylist and use it in forming the copybook message.

We did research about it in the web and found that we can add a resource to the registry.Is it possible to add a java collection to the registry.

Comment: Show some effort and post what you have tried. Show your particular problem and what you have researched so far.

Comment: well, we havent done anything concrete, we are trying to find different approaches to the requirement.There is a set of values in a arraylist and we need to store and access it from wso2 esb(preferable registry). For each message coming in via the JMS proxy we need to retreive and remove the field from the arraylist and use it in forming the copybook message.sorry if my post was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

since u have not provided any specific approach, we can only give you an idea of implementation.

wso2 registry can only hold ur values in a form of xml, where each element contains a specific data ur looking for.

WSO2 provide an approach of writing ur own class mediator. Store all ur values in a property xml and then u can access them using property mediator. like below.

```html
<property xmlns:sample="example.com"
          name="externalProperties"
          expression="get-Property('registry', 'conf:myResources/properties.xml')"
          scope="default"
          type="OM"/>

<property xmlns:sample="example.com"
          name="sampleElement"
          expression="$ctx:externalProperty//element1"
          scope="default"
          type="STRING"/>
```

[NB: ur property must contain a tag named element1 and property file name should be externalProperties]
Now inside class mediator use property externalProperties as arguement

```
public class ManipulateValues implements Mediator {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ManipulateValues .class);

private OMElement externalProperties;

public DiscountQuoteMediator(Omelement elem){
    this.externalProperties = elem;
}

public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {

    //manipulate the externalproperties variable
    return true;
}
```

}

to get the message context use mc arguement in mediate() method.